# Conditional subsetting gone wrong in R

Tags: r, subset

So I have this fairly basic problem with R subsetting, but because I'm a newbie I don't know how to solve it properly. There's example of some panel data I have:

```
   idnr year  sales space municipality   pop
 1    1 2004 110000  1095          136 71377
 2    1 2005 110000  1095          136 71355
 3    1 2006 110000  1095          136 71837
 4    1 2007 120000  1095          136 72956
 5    2 2004  35000   800          136 71377
 6    3 2004  45000  1000          136 71377
 7    3 2005  45000  1000         2584 23135
 8    3 2006  45000  1000         2584 23258
 9    3 2007  45000  1000         2584 23407
 10   4 2005 180000  5000         2584 23254
 11   4 2006 220000  5000         2584 23135
 12   4 2007 250000  5000         2584 23258
```

So my problem is that I want to subset data using conditions for both year = 2004 AND (not or) year = 2005. However it doesn't seem to work. Code:

```
 tab3 <- stores[stores$year==2004 & stores$year==2005, c("idnr","year")]
```

What I am trying to say is that I need to select data which existed in both 2004 and 2005, cause some entries existed either in 2004 or 2005, but not in both and hence should be excluded. Using data above as an example, this should be the output:

```
 idnr year
 1    2004
 1    2005
 3    2004
 3    2005
```

**Update:**

I was hoping that akrun's method may work for selecting data entries, which appeared ONLY in 2005. Such that:

```
 idnr year
 4    2005
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't. Instead it groups both idnr's which appeared in 2004&2005 with those which appeared only in 2005. Any ideas?

Comment: You cannot have at the same time 2004 AND 2005. You can have 2004 OR 2005.

Comment: How unfortunate, because I need to select data from the whole list based on whether it is both in 2004 and 2005. Cause there are some entries who exist only either in 2004 or 2005 - this doesn't suffice.

Comment: That is why you need to do as answered below: use `|` instead of `&`.

Comment: Using | instead includes values which existed in 2004, but not in 2005 and other way around (existed in 2005, but not in 2004). What I am trying to do is that it subset data which existed in BOTH 2004 and 2005.

Comment: So your first statement was not clear at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a an option using "data.table".  Convert the dataset ("df") to "data.table" using `setDT`.  Set the "year" column as "key" (`setkey(..)`).  Subset the rows that have "2004/2005" in the "year" columns (`J(c(2004,..)`), select the first two columns `1:2`.

```
library(data.table) # data.table_1.9.5 
DT1 <- setkey(setDT(df),year)[J(c(2004,2005)), 1:2, with=FALSE]
DT1
#    idnr year
#1:    1 2004
#2:    2 2004
#3:    3 2004
#4:    1 2005
#5:    3 2005
#6:    4 2005
```

#### Update

Based on the updated expected result, we can check whether there are more than one unique "year" entries (`uniqueN(year)>1`) per "idnr" group, get the row index (`.I`) as a column ("V1") and subset the data.table "DT1".

```
 DT1[DT1[, .I[uniqueN(year)>1], idnr]$V1,]
 #     idnr year
 #1:    1 2004
 #2:    1 2005
 #3:    3 2004
 #4:    3 2005
```

Or everything in one liner

```
setDT(df)[year %in% 2004:2005, if(uniqueN(year) > 1L) year, idnr]
#    idnr   V1
# 1:    1 2004
# 2:    1 2005
# 3:    3 2004
# 4:    3 2005
```

Or a `base R` option would be

```
 indx <- with(df, ave(year==2004, idnr, FUN=any)& ave(year==2005, 
                     idnr, FUN=any) & year %in% 2004:2005)
 df[indx,1:2]
 #  idnr year
 #1    1 2004
 #2    1 2005
 #6    3 2004
 #7    3 2005
```

#### Update2

Based on the dataset and the expected result showed, we can check whether the first value of "year" is 2005 for each group "idnr".  If it is TRUE, then subset the first observation (`.SD[1L,..]`) and select the columns that are needed.

```
   setDT(df)[,if(year[1L]==2005) .SD[1L,1,with=FALSE], by = idnr]
   #   idnr year
   #1:    4 2005
```

Or

```
   setDT(df)[df[,.I[year[1L]==2005] , by = idnr]$V1[1L], 1:2, with=FALSE]
   #   idnr year
   #1:    4 2005
```

Comment: Something like that, however it still includes data entries which started existing only in 2005.

Comment: I have included my expected output. Hopefully that clarifies

Comment: @DavidArenburg I dont' understand why you deleted your answer.  I was just complimenting your solution.

Comment: Because it seems too similar to yours

Comment: @akrun I've updated question with other issue. I've tried using your solution with different logical operators however it doesn't seem to produce the desired output. Any ideas?

Comment: @user3691532 I didn't understand your question.  If you select for rows that have year as `2005`, there should be 3 rows.  How do you select only for idnr 4?  If you look at the dataset, `idnr` years 2005, 2006, and 2007 rows are there for idnr 4.

Comment: @akrun. Essentially what I am trying to do is to find the number of incumbents, entrants and exits every year. Basically if the company exists in 2004, but not longer does in 2005 it has exited the market in 2005 whereas if the company didn't exist in 2004, but has appeared in 2005 it has entered the market. Incumbent company has stayed throughout the given period. So what I'm trying to do is to summarize the number of exits, entries and incumbents every year by subletting the data. As you can see from the example idnr 2 has exited the market in 2005, whereas idnr 4 has entered in 2005.

Comment: @user3691532 I updated the results.  Please check if this helps

Comment: @akrun yes, it definitely provides the output I needed. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you want to subset with either `year == 2004` **or** `year == 2005`, you need to use the `|` operator instead of `&` in your actual approach:

```
tab3 <- stores[stores$year == 2004 | stores$year == 2005, c("idnr", "year")]
```

Which results:

```
#> tab3
#   idnr year
#1     1 2004
#2     1 2005
#5     2 2004
#6     3 2004
#7     3 2005
#10    4 2005
```

Or using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
tab3 <- stores %>% select(idnr, year) %>% filter(year == 2004 | year == 2005)
```

More concisely:

```
tab3 <- stores %>% select(idnr, year) %>% filter(year %in% c(2004, 2005))
```

Comment: `stores$year %in% c(2004, 2005)` could save some typing

Comment: How does this answer the question? OP didn't want just to filter by 2004 and 2005. Also as mentioned, `%in%` will also work, but I don't think that addresses the actual question

Comment: @DavidArenburg: This was answering OP initial question. I don't know if you have noticed but there were 2 significant updates in OP. I just didn't have the time to follow along and update the answer (my answer is actually in the state of akrun's first shot). As mentionned by Pascal in the comments, the first statement wasn't clear at all.